# error MonetDBLite or DBI package

Tags: syntax-error

Someone would know how to correct this type of error:

> dbdir <- "~.../test_monet/"
>   mdb <- dbConnect( MonetDBLite::MonetDBLite(), dbdir)
>   monetdb.read.csv(conn = dbdir, 
>   +                  files = '~.../CURSO_2.csv', 
>   +                  tablename = 'curso_2015', 
>   +                  header = TRUE, 
>   +                  na.strings = '', 
>   +                  delim = ';')
>   Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
>     unable to find an inherited method for function ‘dbBegin’ for signature ‘"character"’